# Do you need to pay an extra $300 to be able to retrieve data from the Emotiv Epoc via the python-emotiv library?

Tags: eeg, software

In the Emotiv website, they offer to pay an extra $300 to access "raw EEG data". If I don't pay that, will I still be able to retrieve the EEG data with the python-emotiv library?

Answer (score 2):

For the non-eeg emotiv Epoc, the SDK only offers to retrieve the actions and their values detected from the device. But no raw data.